# Как в C++ 20 ограничить шаблон целочисленными типами (int, long, long long, unsigned long long)?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

В последней (20-й) версии С++ появились конструкции которые позволяют каким то образом ограничить template. Однако как это правильно сделать я пока не могу разобраться.

Помогите мне ограничить функцию только целочисленными типами.

```
/*
 * For a given number the function returns unsorted vector of it's factors.
 * Time Complexity of the algorithm is O(sqrt(N)).
 */
template <class T>
vector<T> factors(T number) {
    vector<T> divisors;

    for (T divisor = sqrt(number); divisor > 0; --divisor) {
        if (number % divisor == 0) {
            divisors.push_back(divisor);
            T paired_divisor = number / divisor;
            if (paired_divisor != divisor) {
                divisors.push_back(paired_divisor);
            }
        }
    }
    return divisors;
}
```

Comment: Заголовок не совпадает с вопросом. Хотите только типы из списка, или любые целочисленные типы?

Comment: Пусть только целочисленные. Для которых имеет смысл функция «делители числа»

Answer (score 5):

Под целочисленные типы в стандартной библиотеке есть готовый [концепт](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/integral). Пользоваться им можно вот так:

```
#include <concepts>

template <std::integral T>
vector<T> factors(T number) {...}
```

---

Свои концепты можно делать так:

`template <` параметры (например `typename T`) `> concept` имя `=` булево выражение (константа времени компиляции).

Например, `std::integral` задается как `template <typename T> concept integral = std::is_integral_v<T>;`.

Для использования концептов есть куча вариантов синтаксиса. Попробую сжато описать:

- Просто как булево выражение, например `if (std::integral<T>)`
- `template <std::integral T>`
  Обратите внимание, что тут не указывается шаблонный параметр концепта - в него ставится `T`. Если параметров больше одного, то все кроме первого нужно указывать самому, например `template <std::derived_from<X> T>` принимает любые `T`, для которых истинно `std::derived_from<T, X>`.
- В C++20 разрешили `auto` в параметрах функций (как в лямбдах), что неявно создает шаблон.
  Теперь и там и там можно делать еще и так: `void foo(std::integral auto x)`.
- В целом в C++20 можно вешать произвольное условие-ограничение на шаблон, в виде булевого выражения.
  `template <std::integral T>` эквивалентно `template <typename T> requires std::integral<T>`. Для шаблонов функций `requires` можно указывать не только после шаблонных параметров, но и после обычных параметров - разница минимальная.
- Возможно еще что-то забыл.